# How to auto adjust the bar with respect to the plotBand option in xrange highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have applied the plotBand option for the xrange chart where the first row is small than the second on , but when resizing the window the data series are not aligned with the plotBand area.

Currently I'm modifying the `y` and `height` of the series by using css, is there any way to make it dynamic to fit into the plotBand area during window resizing.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/t1Ldnc69/13/

[image]

also the green bar not aligned to the plotBand area

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `plotBands` to the `groupPadding` value:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    yAxis: {
        plotBands: [{
            from: -0.3,
            to: 0.3,
            color: '#00401f'
        }, {
            from: 0.7,
            to: 1.3,
            color: '#2f4776'
        }],
        ...
    },
    series: [{
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.2,
        ...
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/orpvc50t/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.groupPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.pointPadding